# ViewDidLoad wont fire after pushed to new viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xamarin

So I am trying to get from one viewcontroller to another using the push segue (selected in the storyboard). When I arrive at the second viewcontroller, the viewDidLoad is not firing! Is that a bug or am I doing everything wrong?

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I didnt do it programmatically, I connected the segue from the storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really hard to give suggestion to this kind of question,

Double check below things once.

1. Is Storyboard View-controller has the Class as the SecondViewController.h
2. Is the 'View' connected to the outlet as the Seccndviewcontrooler's View.
3. Performing segue are you sure pushing the SecondViewcontroller only.
4. Clean build the proj once.
5. just run the app - Place a NSLog Statment in right after the [super viewDidLoad] and see is that printing logs in console.
6. try keeping a breakpoint or NSLog at viewWillAppear/viewdidAppear.

Comment: Fixed it. Had to change


    "public Settings () : base ("Settings", null)"

to


    "public Settings (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)"
Any ideas why?

Comment: What is Setting ?? Its better if you post the snippet of your code and many people here help you out.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by pushed to new view? ViewControllers can be pushed not View. ViewDidLoad will  be fired only when a ViewController is loaded into the memory. It can also be fired if the VC was unloaded by iOS runtime and is being loaded again.

But thumb rule is that it will fire only when the VC is being loaded not afterwards. Please elaborate your question further if I am interpreting you incorrectly.

Comment: I used the push segue from one viewcontroller to another, and it works, i get to the second viewcontroller, but the viewdidload will not fire